# How to create a makefile to share githooks

Tags: git, shell, makefile, pre-commit-hook

I have created a `pre-commit` hook which runs a linter. the `pre-commit` files exist in `<project>\.githooks\pre-commit.sh`. Now, I want to share this hook with team members via make file

so in makefile i did

```
.PHONY: all githooks
githooks:
    root="$(pwd)"
    ln -s "$root/.githooks" "$root/.git/hooks"
```

I get error

```
$ make githooks
root=""
ln -s "oot/.githooks" "oot/.git/hooks"
ln: oot/.git/hooks: No such file or directory
make: *** [githooks] Error 1
```

it looks like that i am not reading `$pwd` into variable and i am unable to join 2 strings. How would i do that in `makefile`?

---

Update:

I have changed the hook to

```
githooks:
    root="$$(pwd)"; \
    ln -s "$$root/.githooks" "$$root/.git/hooks"
```

and here is the output of make file

```
[  1:31PM ]  [ ~ ]
 $ make githooks                 
root="$(pwd)"; \
        ln -s "$root/.githooks" "$root/.git/hooks"
[  1:32PM ]  [ ~ ]
 $ find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls
```

The find command didn't return any links. I tried `git commit` and the hook didn't get triger.

Comment: Pretty sure the find didn't return any links because you were looking in your root where the link target is, not the .git directory where the link to that target is.

Comment: Does `.git` exist prior to running `make githooks`? `ln` won't create the directory.

Comment: Yeah, it does exist.

Comment: `find` does not show the link due to `-maxdepth` option. You should be using `-maxdepth 2` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1. Each line in a recipe is executed in a separate shell; `root` is defined in the first shell, but not in the shell that executes `ln`. The entire script needs to be on one *logical* line in the recipe.
2. `$(pwd)` attempts to expand a Makefile variable named `pwd` before executing the line. To preserve the command substitution, double the `$`: `$$(pwd)`. Likewise, `$$root` is needed to pass `$root` for the shell to expand. Right now, `$root` is trying to expand the Makefile variable `r`, which is also not defined, followed by the literal text `oot`.

A correct recipe would be

```
githooks:
        root="$$(pwd)"; \
        ln -s "$$root/.githooks" "$$root/.git/hooks"
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. I have updated the details in the questin.